Grub2.12 multiboot2 boot failed and gave me an error that unsupported tag:0x8
Below there is my assembly code for multiboot2 header,I cannot find out the error occurs with the grub2.12's error message,so does anyone can look up my multiboot2 header written by me and find out where the error occurs:
Here is my assembly code:
bits 32
header_start:
; magic number
dd 0xe85250d6
; architecture
dd 0
; header length
dd header_end - header_start
; checksum
dd - (0xe85250d6 + 0 + (header_end - header_start))
bootinfo_request_tag:
    dd 1
    dd bootinfo_request_tag_end - bootinfo_request_tag
    dd 6    ; memory map
    dd 1    ; boot command line
    dd 8    ; framebuffer info
    dd 12   ; efi64 system table pointer
bootinfo_request_tag_end:
framebuffer_tag:
    dd 5 ;type
    dd 20 ;size
    dd 800 ; width
    dd 600 ; height
    dd 32   ; depth
framebuffer_tag_end:
    dd 0
framebuffer_tag_info:
    dd 8 ;type
    dd 38 ;size
    dq 256*1024*1024 ;address
    dd 1 ;pitch per byte
    dd 800 ;width
    dd 600 ;height
    db 4 ;bytes per pixel
    db 1 ;colour type
    dw 0 ;reserved
    db 8 ;red_field_position
    db 8 ;red_mask_size
    db 16 ;green_field_position
    db 8 ;green_mask_size
    db 24 ;blue_field_position
    db 8 ;blue_mask_size
framebuffer_tag_info_end:

end_tag:
dd 0
dd 8
header_end:

And here is the error:(in the snapshot)
Error in the snapshot
I want to solve this error without change the structure of my multiboot2 header,I want to enter the graphic mode using grub2's multiboot2 header and draw something in the screen.So does anyone have idea to solve this problem?I know the multiboot2 is 8 aligned tags so when I get the error about 0x8 I get confused.

Type 8 isn't a valid HEADER tag. Remove it. That tag is for a multiboot structure passed to your kernel with information about the framebuffer that GRUB gives you.

The sample kernel.c in the Multiboot2 documentation shows you how to parse out the MULTIBOOT_TAG_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER (type 8) tag that is passed to your kernel: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot2/multiboot.html#kernel_002ec. With that tag you can query for the framebuffer address and then write to it.

OK,I will try your solution.Moreover,I will asked you if I get new error after you posted your solution.
